# How to remove double quotes from column field value of csv file,that is copy to a table in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, copy

I used    `\copy parts from home/sherin_ag/parts.csv with (format csv, header false)` this command on bash  the problem  is on of the  row in csv  column value   comtain double quotes between the characters

**example:** **"35387","20190912","X99","1/4" KEYWAY","KEYWAY","1","FORD"**

The problem is  **"1/4" KEYWAY"**    it contain a double quotes after **1/4**
so i got an error like

> ERROR:  unterminated CSV quoted field

Comment: The csv is invalid, if you have a quote in a field, it must be escaped. Whatever generated that data is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSV is invalid, since it has an unescaped `"` in a record with the same character as quote character. As @404 said, the generated csv file is the problem.

That being said,  you can correct the file beforehand using [`sed`](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) from your console, e.g:

```
 cat vasher_dummy.txt | sed -r 's/\" /\\"" /g' | psql db -c "COPY t FROM STDIN CSV"
```

This command will search for every occurrence of `"_` ( _ meaning space) in your file and will replace it with an escaped `"`

```
SELECT * FROM t;
   a   |    b     |  c  |      d       |   e    | f |  g   
-------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+---+------
 35387 | 20190912 | X99 | 1/4\" KEYWAY | KEYWAY | 1 | FORD
(1 Zeile)
```

If it isn't the only problem you have in your file, you'll have to change the `sed` string to make further corrections. Check the sed documentation.. it's really powerful.

**Update** based on the comments: the OP needs a counter for each line and needs to filter out a few lines.

```
nl -ba -nln -s, < vasher_dummy.txt | sed -r 's/\" /\ /g' | grep 'SVCPTS' | psql db -c "COPY t FROM STDIN CSV"
```

Comment: Thanks for response.actually   this is  my code,  parts.txt  file contain

SVCOP,"35387","20190912","X99","","C","8","7.5","624.78","225.00","34.93","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"
SVCPTS,"35387","20190912","X99","1/4" KEYWAY","KEYWAY","1","1.50","3.00","1.50","3.00","FO","1","FORD"

bash code is:

nl -ba -nln -s, < home/sherin_ag/parts.txt | grep 'SVCPTS' > home/sherin_ag/parts.csv
        psql_local <<SQL || die "Failed to import employee data"
        \copy parts from home/sherin_ag/parts.csv with (format csv, header false)
SQL

Comment: @SherinGreen can you add this update to your question? Just to make sure we don't have any formatting issue or even missing newlines :)

Comment: My text file contain double quotes for each field  but   its work fine with copy  but the problem is when an additional  "   is coming in   values

Comment: @SherinGreen exactly. That's why you have to either remove this additional `"` or escape them to `\"` using `sed`.

Comment: nl -ba -nln -s, < home/sherin_ag/parts.txt | grep 'SVCPTS' > home/sherin_ag/parts.csv | sed -r 's/\" /\\"" /g' 
        psql_local <<SQL || die "Failed to import employee data"
        \copy parts from home/sherin_ag/parts.csv with (format csv, header false)
SQL
i used sed but    insertion not working due to   same error

Comment: are you taking the file content from the disk or using `stdin`? the commands `cat file.csv | sed -r 's/\" /\\"" /g'` before `psql` work just fine

Comment: check this screen shot  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e9bmkPQ4SMOhjr2Hu_e-KFSzQZ7KEw2E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i am using from the disk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203751/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-sherin-green).